# Amazon Aurora RDS unable to use import file . Access denied for user in Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-aurora

I have created an amazon aurora rds database instance and successfully connected with Mysql Workbench with master user.Queries are also working fine, But i do not have all the privileges necessary to perform file import operations. I have read many documentations and threads related to this but am not able to GRANT privileges to Master user. Step by step guidance will be highly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to enable import from file.
First create new parameter group and enable local_infile by value 1.
make a connection with RDS from terminal using

mysql --local-infile --user=username -p --host=hostName.amazonaws.com